# Does including the site name in a link help me to get more pages indexed?

Tags: search-engines

I have my links set up like this:

```
<a href="http://abc.com/test/abc">
<a href="http://abc.com/test/def">
```

the abc.com is repeated many times. What I would like to know is if I need include this at all. How about if I code the links as:

```
<a href="/test/abc">
<a href="/test/def">
```

Would a search engine consider these the same as the links with abc.com?

Answer (score 5):

Those two examples are identical and won't have any effect on your rankings or pages indexed.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, you won't have any benefits.